# CSS jquery moving a div from bottom to top using pixels

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, jsfiddle

Hey all i have a JSFiddle that i have been working on with trying to get it to animate going from bottom to top instead of what its currently doing, top to bottom.

This will be used as a animated bar graph for a fund raiser amount that's in front of an image and this bar graph will represent the amount in dollars they have raised so far.

The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/YDruG/

Any help would be great!!!

**update**

The HTML code:

```
<a href="#" id="button">View 100 (out of 500)</a>

<div id="barGraph-container">
    <div id='barGraph'></div>
</div>​
```

The JS:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#barGraph').animate({height:'72px'}, 500);
});
```

​
The CSS:

```
#barGraph-container {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
#barGraph {
    height: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}​
```

Comment: it is nice placing the code as well besides the jsfiddler

Comment: put it in a table where it is vertical aligned to the bottom...then when the height changed it would go bottom to top.

Comment: Fixed your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZeu3/4/) to use jQuery. You had it set to use MooTools.

Comment: Updated with code for you @EdwinSoho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a container around your bar graph and use absolute positioning to anchor it to the bottom of the container.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/YDruG/

Comment: It's still animating downward. I need it to start from the bottom and animate upwards.

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/YDruG/ (I set the initial height of the bar to '0')

Answer (score 0):

By giving the graph bar a relative position, and adding a top position animation to compensate for the reduced height, you can achieve this quite easily.

http://jsfiddle.net/GZeu3/19/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses 2 divs to "reveal" the graph which looks like it is growing.

http://jsfiddle.net/GZeu3/23/

Comment: Code is available at the link provided